# Failed to connect to the remote extension host server (Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\aymer\.ssh\config')

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am on Windows 10 and when I want to connect to distant server with VSCode, I have this error:

```
Failed to connect to the remote extension host server (Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\aymer\.ssh\config')
```

Yet, I have checked the permissions for this file (config) and .ssh folder and they allow me to use them

Regards

[EDIT] something weird is that C:\Users\aymer.ssh\config is on my local computer, not on the distant server, so why VScode is trying to open it ?